# Squarefree numbers $n$ such that $432n+1$ is also squarefree

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem

This is a second attempt (see [Primes $p$ such that $432 p +1$ is prime](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177846/primes-p-such-that-432-p-1-is-prime))

Is the set of squarefree numbers $n$ such that $n(432 n+1)$ is also squarefree known to be infinite?

Fact: the number of such numbers $n$ such that $n\leq 10^6$ is precisely $553095$. Do we expect that $$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\# \{n  \leq x\ : \ n \ \textrm{is squarefree integer, and } 432n+1 \ \textrm{is squarefree}\}}{x} = 1/2?$$

Comment: I don't have time to work this out, but the density is the product of local densities, which is surely not $1/2$ but some more complicated number (probably transcendental). That is, for each prime $p$ let $c_p$ denote the density of $n$'s such that $n(432n+1)$ is not divisible by $p^2$, and then the density in the post will be $\prod_p c_p$.

Comment: What is so special about 432?

Comment: See my response here how to do this for $n(n+1)$: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/172009/probability-that-n-is-coprime-to-both-m-and-m1/

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It appears in my set-up. That's all unfortunately.

Comment: I think you should put more about the motivation in the question, then.

Comment: @GHfromMO Thank you. So I should be able to follow that approach to see that the global density is positive by simply showing the local densities are positive. Correct?

Comment: Actually that post is not so good as I realized. Anyways, I would start the proof with the formula $\mu^2(k)=\sum_{d^2\mid k}\mu(d)$ which picks the square-free numbers.

Comment: @GHfromMO I don't understand your formula. That number is zero when $k>1$,  right? I guess you meant to consider the absolute value of $\mu(d)$ in the summand.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now. Another natural approach is to fix $P$, sieve with the primes $p\leq P$, and estimate the contribution of $p>P$ seperately.

Comment: @GHfromMO Yes, but shouldn't it be much easier to just prove infinitenes directly? Or is this somehow the standard "easy" approach?

Comment: @GHfromMO Ok, so I need to consider  $\sum_{k=1}^x \mu^2(k) \mu^2(432 k +1) = \sum_{k=1}^x (\sum_{d^2 \vert k} \mu(d) ) (\sum_{e^2\vert 432 k+1} \mu(e))$

Comment: Actually, thinking a bit about it, the problem is not so simple because the error terms can add up to a constant times $x$. At any rate, Estermann proved in 1931 that for any nonzero $k$ there are infinitely many $n$'s such that $n^2+k$ is square-free. I am sure the approach there can be easily modified to yield what you need. I found Estermann's paper in a more recent paper by Heath-Brown (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.6217.pdf). Estermann's paper is also online: http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0105&DMDID=dmdlog34

Comment: Actually the problem can be settled with a simple inclusion-exclusion sieve as I anticipated above. See my response for the details.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a quick proof that the density in question exists and equals
$$ c:=\frac{2}{3}\prod_{p\geq 5}\left(1-\frac{2}{p^2}\right)\approx 0.553087\ . $$

Let $f(d)$ denote the number of solutions of the congruence $n(432n+1)\equiv 0\pmod{d}$. Note that, for $p$ prime, $f(p^2)=1$ when $p<5$ and $f(p^2)=2$ when $p\geq 5$. Let $P\geq 2$ be fixed. By a simple inclusion-exclusion sieve combined with the Chinese remainder theorem, we see that the number of $n\leq x$ such that $n(432n+1)$ is not divisible by the square of any prime $p\leq P$, equals
$$ x\prod_{p\leq P}\left(1-\frac{f(p^2)}{p^2}\right)+o_P(x)=x\prod_p\left(1-\frac{f(p^2)}{p^2}\right)+o_P(x)+O(x/P).$$
Observe that the infinite product on the right equals $c$. On the other hand, the number of $n\leq x$ such that $n(432n+1)$ is divisible by the square of some prime $p>P$, is at most
$$ \sum_{p>P}O(x/p^2)=O(x/P).$$
Altogether we see that the number of $n\leq x$ such that $n(432n+1)$ is square-free, equals
$cx+o_P(x)+O(x/P)$. In particular, both the lower and the upper density of these numbers equals $c+O(1/P)$. These quantities are independent of $P$, hence upon letting $P\to\infty$, we see that they both equal $c$. So the density exists and also equals $c$.

For related comments see the introduction of [this 1953 paper by Erdős](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1953-02.pdf).